# How to draw a line between draggable and droppable?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drawing, svg

I'm using the excellent JQuery UI to do a "mapping" so the user can "map"
persons from one program to persons from other program.

using this simple JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div .draggable").draggable({
        revert: 'valid',
        snap: false
    });

    $("div .droppable").droppable({
        hoverClass: 'ui-state-hover',
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this)
                .addClass('ui-state-highlight')
                .find("img")
                .removeAttr("src")
                .attr("src", "_assets/img/icons/check-user-48x48.png");

            $(this).droppable('disable');

            $(ui.draggable)
                .addClass('ui-state-highlight')
                .find("img")
                .removeAttr("src")
                .attr("src", "_assets/img/icons/check-user-48x48.png");

            $(ui.draggable).draggable('disable');
        }
    });

    $("div .droppable").bind("dblclick", function() {
        $(this)
            .removeClass('ui-state-highlight')
            .find("img")
            .removeAttr("src")
            .attr("src", "_assets/img/icons/user-48x48.png");
        $(this).droppable('enable');

        EnableSource($(this));
    });
});
```

I get to this:

[image]

**what I really wanted** was (if possible) create a line between 
**Elsa** and **Kjell** so it makes the connection between them clear.

I can always do it with numbers inside the boxes, but I really 
wanted to know how to do this using the lines.

**Thanks**.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

- **updated (08.Jul.2013)** Updated with latest versions of libraries; html refactored using JsRender;
- **updated (29.Sep.2011)** Added GIT Repo; cleaned the code; update to latest framework versions;
- **updated (03.Mar.2013)** Fixed links with working example;

Current example uses:

- HTML 5 doctype
- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) v.1.10.2
- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) v.1.10.3
- [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) v.2.0.1
- [JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) v.1pre35 *(optional, used for HTML simplification)*

Source

> [Source code in **Git Repository**](https://github.com/balexandre/Draggable-Line-to-Droppable)

Demo

> [Page demo at JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/aliniz/2/edit)

---

Works on **FF**, **IE**, **Chrome**, **Safari** and **Opera**.

tested on:

- Firefox 6 and 7 .. 22
- IE 8 and 9  .. 10
- Chrome 12+  .. 27
- Safari 5+   .. 6
- Opera 11.51 .. 15

to show you all, I just made a little demo of my accomplishment (I am a proud person today!):

> [**Video demo**](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/showFlash.aspx?swf=2009-08-19_1126_StackOverflow_DragLine.swf&w=936&h=652)

and a little image:

[image]

Comment: only if you use Silverlight :( no SVG support in IE8 either, only in FF.

Comment: "no one uses that" :) ... it was working only on FF, and now FF and IE ... one browser at a time mate ;) -> I use FF in my Mac ;)

Comment: i looked into this quickly, it seems like you could do this with excanvas.  similary to what flot (http://code.google.com/p/flot/) does.

Comment: i tried that page using IE7 and it didn't work.  did you test using IE8?

Comment: I use IE 8 here and works fine... I'll make a new ScreenCast showing both browsers

Comment: added new screencast with IE8, FF3 and Chrome

Comment: There's only 1 bug: if you drop short of a person the box stays there.  Thus the box, when dropped on a person, goes back to its misplaced position and a line is drawn there.  You should implement a snap-back when not dropped on a valid target.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the algorithm used for the line, when the box is misplaced, doesn't connect properly; the line goes to the center of the recipient, it would seem.

Comment: @The Wicked Flea your right :) this was something I started to answer my own question, some more things to accomplish to have it right. But is a good place to start if someone is searching for the same behavior, don't you agree?

Comment: I use the Helper as a clone object ... works nicely, thanks for the feedback @The Wicked Flea

Comment: buggy in current chrome. Also: line do not redraw after resize of the browser window (e.g. responsive behaviour)

Comment: @Submit we're not here to do your homework... take the project that is in GIT and use it if you want, improve it if you like... but this is a 2009 question...

Comment: It worked fine.
But when I try on the mobile, it doesn't worked.
Anyone can help this please?

Comment: @BestMob this was something I made in 2009 ... I tried to simply update to make it work during the next years when the tooling had breaking changes but only for this example. Nowadays, maybe there might be a better way to do it?...

Comment: It would be great if you can make touch event working on the mobile soon, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'm too new to post a link but if you google "Library for simple drawing with jQuery", you may find what you're looking for. :)

[link here](http://www.openstudio.fr/Library-for-simple-drawing-with.html)

Comment: I googled, this page was the first reference to what I really had in mind, mmm, thank you @balexandre