# Jquery - get list position

Tags: jquery, list

i have the following code

```
<ul class="MenuMainContent">
        <li class="tabClass clubTab" style="display: none;"><a href="#tabs-1" class=" ">Club</a></li>
        <li class="tabClass eatTab active" style="display: list-item;"><a href="#tabs-2" class="  selected">Eat</a></li>
        <li class="tabClass barTab" style="display: none;"><a href="#tabs-3" class=" ">Drink</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I want to use jquery to get the position of the first visible list item (i.e. where style is not display: none)

Can this be done with jquery?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code you provided, you can get the index of the first visible list item (relative to the `ul` element, using the following jQuery:

`$(".tabClass:visible").index()`

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubWm9/) for an example using your code (it should alert "1", as the first visible list item is in position 1 (the indexing starts at 0).

Answer (score 0):

Not essential to make this work but I would remove the inline styles - adding a style for hidden:

```
 <ul class="MenuMainContent">
    <li class="tabClass clubTab hidden"><a href="#tabs-1" class=" ">Club</a></li>
    <li class="tabClass eatTab active"><a href="#tabs-2" class="  selected">Eat</a></li>
    <li class="tabClass barTab hidden"><a href="#tabs-3" class=" ">Drink</a></li>
</ul>
```

in CSS:

```
 .hidden {display:none;}
```

in jQuery

```
 $('.tabClass.active:first').etc...
```

(Note I'm assuming that "active" class only applied to rows that aren't hidden)

Once you have a reference to the relevant item then refer to this article:
[jQuery x y document coordinates of DOM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002934/jquery-x-y-document-coordinates-of-dom-object)
for how to get it's location.

Answer (score 0):

Definitly yes, you can do this easily with jQuery.

you will utilize the `.Position()` method that get's you the coordinates of your object.

Check this page for more details: http://api.jquery.com/position/

If you couldn't make it, let me know and I may post you the code required, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is want you want

```
  $("ul.MenuMainContent li:visible")
```

working example here http://jsfiddle.net/VXjvS/

You can also add first to it like this

```
$("ul.MenuMainContent li:visible:first").position() to get the position
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get first visible list..

```
$("ul.MenuMainContent li:visible:first").position();
```