# Get Co-ordinates on page load in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a situation. I am using web application of windows(ASP.NET). On page load when my web page appears, it has dynamically generated ImageButtons. I need to fid the X,Y or TOP,LEFT co-ordinates of each ImageButton control on the page WITHOUT CLICKING ON ANY OF THE ImageButtons.. I need to draw a line beetween some ImageButtons on the click of one ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some Javascript code or jQuery. Please find below jQuery code

Here i have used **[position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/)** method which gives you left and top position of the element. You can change the **[selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)** based on your need.

**Update**: Assumed you have HTML like `<div id='images-container'> .. all images here </div>` and updated selector below for that with [**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method

You can also use **[offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#images-container img').each(funcion(){
         var coordinates=$(this).position();
         coordinates.left;// gives you x
         coordinates.top;// gives you y
         //save these values in some hidden field and access it in code behind if needed
       });
    });
 </script>
```

Please refer this post for more information [jQuery x y document coordinates of DOM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002934/jquery-x-y-document-coordinates-of-dom-object)

Comment: @Murli : Thanks Murli. Does this gives me the co-ordinates of each ImageButton that I have on my we Form.? And how to use these values in my C# code

Comment: This code gives the first image button. If you want to take all image button you simply use image selector. $('#images-container img').position() -> this gives all images inside any container like div which is having id='images-container'

Comment: @Murli : How do i do it for the ImageButtons which are generated purely dynamically.? There is no div in .aspx. Everything is generated in .CS file. How to apply abive code in .Cs file. How to use jquery in .CS file.? Plz help.