# How to determine exact position of a dom element regardless of scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I need the bounds of a dom element and use it by shrinking a little, here's my code:

```
var rack = $('.rack')[0];
var rackBounds = rack.getBoundingClientRect();

rackBounds = {
  top: rack.offsetTop + 10
  left: rack.offsetLeft + 10
  height: rackBounds.height - 10
  width: rackBounds.width - 10
};
```

When I use this it works fine, but if I scroll the page to bottom, this fails, why

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle demo

Comment: I am using [greensock](greensock.com/gsap) for drag drop, it doesn't respect these bounds, when I scroll bottom. @Tushar

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002934/jquery-x-y-document-coordinates-of-dom-object

Comment: You may need to create a fiddle for this. Its a little difficult to imagine what the problem might be.