# Jquery Ui Draggable How to get Id of div dragged started in

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I'm dragging and dropping divs between outer container divs and need to get the id of the outer div that the drag started in. 
I'm doing this by saving `$(this.parentNode).attr('id')` on the drag start event.

The first time I drag something this gives the expected div id but on subsequent drags of the same div this id is not correct.

Any ideas please?

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<DragDropTrial.Models.LemonCollection>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        var origleft;
        var origtop;
        var origZ;

        // Make lemons image draggable
        $("img.lemons").draggable({
               start: function(event, ui) {
               origleft = event.clientX;
               origtop = event.clientY;
               origZ = $(this.parentNode).attr('id');
               },
                cursor: "move"
            });

        // Make dish div droppable
        $("#dish").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                saveDropDetails(ui.draggable.attr('id'), $(this).attr('id'), ui.absolutePosition.top, ui.absolutePosition.left, origleft, origtop, origZ);
            }
        });
        // Make table div droppable
        $("#table").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                saveDropDetails(ui.draggable.attr('id'), $(this).attr('id'), ui.absolutePosition.top, ui.absolutePosition.left);
            }
        });
        });

    function saveCoords(left, top, dragId) {
        alert("{dragId is : '" + dragId + "',left is : '" + left + "',,top is : '" + top + "'}");
    }
    function saveDropDetails(dragId, dropId, dropPosTop, dropPosLeft, origleft, origtop, origZ) {
        alert("dragId is : " + dragId + ",dropId is : " + dropId + ",dropPosTop is : " + dropPosTop + ",dropPosLeft is : " + dropPosLeft + " origTop is " + origtop + " origLeft is " + origleft + " originZ is " + origZ);
    }
</script>

<h2>Drag and drop the lemons</h2>

    <div id = "table" style = "background-color:Blue">TABLE
          <%foreach (var aLem in Model.Table)    
          { %>
             <img id = "<%=aLem.LemonId %>", alt ="<%=string.Format("Lemon{0}", aLem.LemonId) %>" src="../../Images/extract.png" style ="padding-left:25px" class = "lemons" />

        <%} %>

    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <div id = "dish" style = "background-color:Gray" >DISH
    <p></p>
          <%foreach (var aLem in Model.Dish)    
          { %>
             <img id = "<%=aLem.LemonId %>", alt ="<%=string.Format("Lemon{0}", aLem.LemonId) %>" src="../../Images/extract.png" style ="padding-left:25px" class = "lemons" />

        <%} %>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code, including the code for the drop.

Comment: It might be helpful to see your code. Your drag-drop code is altering the DOM, so its parent is likely going to change when it gets dragged around.

Comment: if you want to add a line between the draggable and the dropable, please read my post on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536676 :)

Comment: Does the problem occur only when you drag an element to a different container more than once?  But it works correctly the first time?

Answer (score 1):

I'll start off by saying it's late and I'm tired.

```
var tables = [], dishes = [];

<%foreach (var aLem in Model.Table)    
{ %>
  tables.push(<%= aLem.LemonId %>);
  <img id = "<%=aLem.LemonId %>", ... class = "lemons" />
<%} %>

<%foreach (var aLem in Model.Dish)    
{ %>
  dishes.push(<%= aLem.LemonId %>);
  <img id = "<%=aLem.LemonId %>", ... class = "lemons" />
<%} %>
```

Now your table lemons and dish lemons won't forget where they came from. There might be better ways but this is it for me - hopefully it's enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks but actually I don't want to know where the lemons originally came from, but rather where they were at the start of each drag. I am aiming at a complete history of where the lemons have been dragged and dropped.