# I would like to draw a line between two dynamic points on a webpage using HTML

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm working within the confines of ASP.NET and HTML.

I have a gridview on the left and a gridview on the right.

When the user selects a checkbox in the left gridview and a checkbox in the right gridview, I would like a line to be rendered that connects the checkboxes.

Is there an efficient way to do this? Anything approaching this?

```
DrawLine(LeftCheckBox.Location, RightCheckbox.Location, Red, 1px)
```

The only thing I can think of that would be work, but be a poor solution, is positioning and stretching an Image vertically based upon where the selected checkboxes are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [jQuery drawing library](http://www.openstudio.fr/Library-for-simple-drawing-with.html?lang=fr).

Also you might find this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536676/how-to-draw-a-line-between-draggable-and-droppable) very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Walter Zorn's javascript graphics library. Unfortunately, his site is not maintained anymore. The last version with documentation and example can be found here:
http://www.c-point.com/javascript_vector_draw.htm

Drawing a line is as easy as:

```
jg.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 200);
```

This probably is a little outdated because we have the canvas element now, but still works fine cross-browser.