# How to drag and drop a div changing the css left and top attributes in HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop

I would like to perform a drag and drop on a div in HTML 5. The goal is to move a div anywhere in the main container.

Here is my html code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mon document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dragndrop.js"></script>
</head>

<body ondragstart="dragStart(event);" ondragover="return dragOver(event);" ondrop="return drop(event);">
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
        Drag me if you can !
    </div>
</body>
```

The style.css :

```
.box {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 400px;
      color: white;
      background-color: #6495ED;
      border: 10px solid #6495ED;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px #999; 
      box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px #555;
      border-radius: 7px; 
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
}

body {
      background-color:#EEEEEE;
}
```

And the javascript :

```
var mouseX;                         // Current mouse X           coordinate
var mouseY;                         // Current mouse Y  coordinate

document.onmousemove = mouseMove;

function dragStart(event) {
event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.getAttribute('id'));
}

function dragOver(event) {
return false;
}

function drop(event) {
ev = event || window.event;
mouseX = ev.pageX;
mouseY = ev.pageY;

var element = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

document.getElementById(element).style.left = mouseX+"px";
document.getElementById(element).style.top = mouseY+"px";

event.stopPropagation();

return false;
}
```

It does not work, so I think there is something wrong in the javascript function drop. But I can not see what (I never worked with js before that).

Thanks for help.

Comment: why not using jQuery UI? see my question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536676/how-to-draw-a-line-between-draggable-and-droppable long time I don't change the source, to play with newer versions but you will get it.

Comment: I'd rather not. And I thought this was something pretty easy to do with html 5...

Comment: for your own sake, never do anything like this in HTML5, a lot still use IE8/7, FF3, etc ... where there is no support for such fancy things :)

Comment: @balexandre haha, dude, IE introduced this and MANY HTML API's. Good try though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will follow this good advice and use jquery instead.
I found here the demo and code I need : [jQuery UI - draggable demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).