# Need: HTML 5 / Javascript UI Component to do "Matching"/"Data Mapping" UI

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a Javascript UI component which will let me drag a line between items in a hierarchical tree on one side of the screen to items in a hierarchical tree on the other side of the screen (similar to BizTalk's "Map" UI).

I've searched for "Javascript Tree Map", etc. and have only found "Treemap"s... which are not at all what I'm looking for.

I'm perfectly fine with requiring HTML5 and using canvas.

I just don't want to write this myself if there is already something out there.

Thanks!

I'm not sure if I can articulate what I'm looking for well, so let me provide an illustration:

[BizTalk Map UI http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/Chilberto/WindowsLiveWriter/BizTalkMapComparisonbetweenTableLoopinga_B5B9/image_6.png](http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/Chilberto/WindowsLiveWriter/BizTalkMapComparisonbetweenTableLoopinga_B5B9/image_6.png)

Comment: I think what you need to do is a [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) with an invisible box and a line constructed to follow the invisible box from the origin.

Comment: @Jared; when you say draggable, you mean like a jQuery draggable?

Comment: @Steve - Yes, see my comment edit.

Comment: @Steve - Btw, I think the line might be tricky too. Hmm...

Comment: @Jared; I admit, I tried to keep the question fairly simple... but I'm really looking for something that could handle collapsible tree nodes and large numbers of connections out-of-the-box. Something more akin to BizTalk's "Map" UI... where the position and visibility of the lines drawn on the canvas would update when the trees are scrolled / collapsed, etc. Lets see what sort of answers we get.

Comment: @Steve - Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536676/how-to-draw-a-line-between-draggable-and-droppable

Comment: @Steve - After seeing your new picture, yeah, I would check ExtJS or some of the other mature and higher-end libraries (maybe even Flash and Silverlight).

Comment: @Jared; Nice Link! That would certainly be a good starting point for me if I need to do it myself. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WireIt](http://neyric.github.com/wireit/) library will enable you to drag lines that connect components.  You may still need to pull in something else to get the hierarchical view on either side though.